# Converting Stars to Shapefile Cannot Allocate Vector of Size 1.6 Gb

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert a raster to a shapefile via stars and sf.  The only problem is that it seems that I do not have enough ram.  All available space (16336mb) is allocated to R via memory.limit(), but I'm running into size issues.

I have 16 GB allocated to R, and before running my code (after running gc()), I am only using 1072.25 mb, and I am only using ~25% of total RAM on my machine.  Running my code immediately raises memory usage, and it fluctuates between 60% and nearly 100% while the code runs, eventually falling to around 45%.  Shortly afterwards, the execution ends with the error and R using 14587.01 mb, despite my computer only being at 45% RAM usage.

How can I fix this?

Code:

```
setwd("F:\\max\\Documents\\School\\Fall 2021\\Research\\Data")
filenames = list.files(".//Annual", pattern="*.nc", full.names=TRUE)
polData = read_stars(filenames[23]) #load data as stars
polSf = st_as_sf(polData) #Try to convert to shapefile (where code fails)
```

Comment: Does this happen even when you *don't* use `memory.limit()`?

Comment: You can turn it off?

Comment: Restarting your R session resets the memory limit options, if you don't save the session.

Comment: I think it would be useful to know whether you're running 32 or 64 bit either and what error message is popping up when your code fails

Comment: The `pattern='*.nc'` refers to netcdf files in your '\\Data' directory? And do you have a general idea of the size of `filenames[23]`?

Comment: As against using `stars::read_ncdf`

Comment: filenames is a vector 23 strings maybe about 20 characters each.  Insignificant.  What about using stars::read_ncdf?

The error message was `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 6.6 Gb` (odd that it went from 1.6 to 6.6